# Mixture regression

Tags: regression, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I am wondering how to analyze and interpret something like the data shown in the figure below (the color is the log-density of the data points, which are a few hundred thousands in number).

My thinking was that the data probably represent a mixture of several components, each of which exhibits linear dependence between the predictor and response variables. SO I tried teh following options:

- Fitting a multinomial mixture model (which better describes the origin of the data) using the EM algorithm. This has not worked, but possibly because I used my own code.
- Treating both variables as normal and using GaussianMixture of sklearn package. The categories obtained are nothing like the rays in the image. I am not sure though that this is a valid approach: the predictor has indeed Gaussin-like distribution, but not teh response variable (which is more gamma-like).
- Another option is that my line of thinking is completely misleading, given that most of the points are cocnentrated near the origin).

Questions:

- What are possible interpretations for these types of data?
- What are the statistical/algorithmic approaches that can be used for the analysis?

[image]